# How to structure a "friendship"

Tags: ms-access

I'm completely new to access. Please don't mind typos or terminological mistakes. I will try to explain my best.

I have a "people" table, including people with unique ID's. Let's assume, there is person1, person2, person3 and person4.

I want to create a structure where each of these people can be friends with each other.

For instance, person1's friends are person3 and person4. this condition should make person3's friend, person1 at the same time.

I'm not sure how I can relate tables like this, or how I can set relationships in tables to give me this as a result.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: create a relationship table that contains 2 columns, personID1 and personID2, make this combination unique and ensure that it's only populated / updated having the lower ID in the personID1 slot

Comment: A little more details would be appreciated. What do you mean by "make this combination unique"? Also, how can I populate it using te lower ID? More importantly, how can I pull th relations information from that table?

I currently have a "relationships" table where I can add personID1 and personID2; there are multiple copies of the same "friendships" since the table allows it right now (but I don't mind) -- the part I can't solve is: how I should pull the information (query?) out of the table to show the relations two sided?

Comment: you are trying to create a graph database in a relational database. You may find this discussion somewhat useful https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-membership-equivalence-classes--cliques/

Comment: Thank you for the information however it's way to complex for me at this point. I was expecting to see a relation graph for MS Access or something similar.

Comment: sorry, Celko's article has a very detailed example, showing both the table creation, the problem analysis and sample queries that addresses your problem. Please spend some minutes reading it and I'm pretty sure you'll find your answer there.

Comment: I did read all of it; unfortunately it didn't help. I'm looking for a way to relate tables in a way that I'll be able to pull out the two-sided information from the relations table. I believe this is an access-specific question then a logic-only question. As I mentioned, I'm new to access and even if I knew the logic I wouldn't be able to create it in access -- that's why this question exits in the first place in the "MS-Access" tag rather than DB tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, representing these types of symmetric relationships is not the strength of a classical relational database.

The friendship relationship can be represented using only 1 simple table, but how you manipulate the data in can become a bit complex.

You have basically 2 ways:

#### Double-entry records

```
Friend table
PK   Field 1       Field 2
--------------------------------
ID   PersonID      FriendWithPersonID
```

With this, if Person Alice (`Person.ID = 123`)  is friend with Bob (`Person.ID = 456`), you would need to enter 2 records:

```
Friend table
ID   PersonID      FriendWithPersonID
--------------------------------
1    123           456
2    456           123
```

Maintaining this data can be difficult: for each operation (Add, Delete), you need to change both records to make sure they stay in sync.

- Adding a friendship needs 2 operations:

  ```
  INSERT INTO Friend (PersonID, FriendWithPersonID) VALUES (123,456);
  INSERT INTO Friend (PersonID, FriendWithPersonID) VALUES (456,123);
  ```
- Deleting a Friendship can be done in one:

  ```
  DELETE FROM Friend 
  WHERE (PersonID=123 AND FriendWithPersonID=456)
     OR (PersonID=456 AND FriendWithPersonID=123)
  ```

To update a relationship, the easiest is to delete it and re-insert a new one.

Now, any query you have to make can be easily done:

- Number of Alice's friends:

  ```
  SELECT Count(*) WHERE PersonID=123
  ```
- List of all Bob's friends:

  ```
  SELECT People.*
  FROM   People
    INNER JOIN Friend
      ON Friend.FriendWithPersonID = People.ID
  WHERE Friend.PersonID = 456
  ```
- Friends that Alice and Bob have in common (I'm reporting the IDs, just to make the query clearer):

  ```
  SELECT FriendWithPersonID
  FROM   Friend
  WHERE  PersonID=123
         AND FriendWithPersonID IN (SELECT FriendWithPersonID
                                    FROM   Friend
                                    WHERE  PersonID=456)
  ```

This system is not perfect though:

- There is always a risk that, over time, errors can mess up the data and make it inconsistent.
- It's also probable that, at some point, you may have a hard time making a query for some

#### Single-entry record

The other way to implement friendship would be to have a single record to describe each friendship.

```
Friend table
PK   Field 1       Field 2
--------------------------------
ID   Person1ID     Person2ID
```

With this, if Person Alice (`Person.ID = 123`)  is friend with Bob (`Person.ID = 456`), you would need to enter 1 record:

```
Friend table
ID   PersonID      Person2ID
--------------------------------
1    123           456
```

Maintaining the relationships opens another kind of issue: we don't know on which side of the relationship each person is.

Creating and deleting records is fairly easy though:

- Adding a friendship needs 1 operations, and it doesn't matter which is `Friend1` or `Friend2`:

  ```
  INSERT INTO Friend (Friend1ID, Friend2ID) VALUES (123,456);
  ```
- Deleting a Friendship is also fairly easy and similar to what we had before in that we need to test both possibilities to delete the single friendship record:

  ```
  DELETE FROM Friend 
  WHERE (Person1ID=123 AND Person2ID=456)
     OR (Person1ID=456 AND Person2ID=123)
  ```

Now, in most cases, we have to rebuild the symmetry using the `UNION` statement so we can present all data in the same column:

- Number of Alice's friends:

  ```
  SELECT Count(*) WHERE Person1ID=123 or Person2=123
  ```
- List of all Bob's friends:

  ```
  SELECT People.*
  FROM   People
         INNER JOIN (SELECT Person2ID AS FriendOfPersonID
                     FROM   Friend
                     WHERE  Person1ID=456
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT Person1ID AS FriendOfPersonID
                     FROM   Friend
                     WHERE  Person2ID=456) AS F
           ON F.FriendOfPersonID = People.ID
  ```

I'll leave the last query as an exercise, you basically also have to use the `UNION` statement.

With that system, you keep the information in the table to a minimum but there are other trade-offs:

- before you add a new relationship, check that there inst' already a reverse one in the system. If you add 2 records for the same relationship, you'll get duplicate results in your queries.
- queries can become quite complicated because you always have to consider that the data you are looking for could be in either column: each query must have some symmetry.